# How to split one single column to multiple columns in Standard sql- Big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Using Google BigQuery

```
  WITH prep AS (
  SELECT 
  SPLIT(offer.name, '-') AS split,
  id
  FROM `hasoffer.offers_new` AS offer
  )

 SELECT *
 FROM
 (
  SELECT
  split[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS Game,
  split[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS GEO,
  IF ( REGEXP_CONTAINS ('INTERNAL - POGED',offers.name), "POGED", 
  IF(REGEXP_CONTAINS ('INTERNAL',offers.name), "Internal", IF( 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS('REDIRECT',offers.name), "REDIRECT", "Public"))) AS 
  Category,
  DATE(conv.datetime) AS Date,
  (SUM(conv.revenue_cents)/100) AS Revenue
  FROM `hasoffer.offers_new` AS offers
  LEFT JOIN
  prep
  ON
  offers.id=prep.id
  LEFT JOIN
  `hasoffer.conversions` AS conv
  ON offers.id = conv.offer_id
  WHERE 
  conv.advertiser_id = 632 
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM conv.datetime) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE())
  AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM conv.datetime) = 2018
  AND conv.status != 'rejected'
  AND conv.affiliate_sub1 IS NOT NULL
  group by
  GEO,
  Game,
  Category,
  Date
  order by
  Date)AS SourceTable
```

This is how the table looks:

[image: This is how the table looks]

Expected output:

[image: Expected Output]

- The column "Date" has to be split into multiple columns each representing a day in a month and should contain value of sum of revenue for different Games and Geos.
- Additionally, a column called Grand total must be created which gives the total revenue of game ad geo for the month. Please suggest a way to do that

Comment: In Standard SQL there's no `split` and a part of a date is extracted using `extract`. Besides that I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please post your expected output also.

Comment: If you click on the image and take a look at the table, you can see a column date. I'm trying to split that column into multiple columns as stated above

Comment: Are you referring to Google's "standard SQL" for Google Big Query?

Comment: You are trying to "Pivot" your data, which is normally something you'd do in a reporting layer *(Such as Google Data Studio)* rather than in SQL.  That said, you can pivot in SQL, if you are explicit about the number of columns you want; so, to write SQL to work for any given month you would need to always have 31 date columns and one grand total, always, even for february.  Is that what you want?  And why are you doing it in SQL rather than Data Studio or some other reporting environment?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah trying it with standard sql

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks, you have interpreted the problem clearly. I'm trying to pivot my data. Yeah I want to create a pivot for 31 days and a grand total in standard sql. The reason for choosing  SQL is because the google sheet supermetrics accepts that. I want my results in google sheet at the end

Comment: @SHARVESHGOPALPREMKUMAR Google Sheets can pivot data too, it has a Pivot Table to do that...  I recommend doing it that way.  *(Or just using Data Studio, as google sheets can't easily query BigQuery, but data studio has that built in natively.)*

Comment: @MatBailie Consumes a lot of processing time coz the data is huge. Hence the SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do the pivotting you want using BigQuery you could use...

```
SELECT
  Game,
  Geo,
  Category,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM Date) = 01 THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END)   AS DAY_OF_MONTH_01,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM Date) = 02 THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END)   AS DAY_OF_MONTH_02,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM Date) = 03 THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END)   AS DAY_OF_MONTH_03,
  ...
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM Date) = 30 THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END)   AS DAY_OF_MONTH_30,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM Date) = 31 THEN Revenue ELSE 0 END)   AS DAY_OF_MONTH_31,
  SUM(Revenue)                                                         AS GRAND_TOTAL
FROM
  yourSource
WHERE
      Date >= DATE '2018-08-01'
  AND Date <  DATE '2018-09-01'
GROUP BY
  Game,
  Geo,
  Category
```

The column headings then don't contain the months, but that's because they can't be derived from the data.  I still think you should pivot in your spreadsheet, using this query as the source...

```
SELECT
  Game,
  Geo,
  Category,
  Date,
  SUM(Revenue)   AS Revenue
FROM
  yourSource
WHERE
      Date >= DATE '2018-08-01'
  AND Date <  DATE '2018-09-01'
GROUP BY
  Game,
  Geo,
  Category,
  Date
```

Then you can't have "huge" data, you just have what you need, and let the sheet pivot it...